# How do I square each item in a list using append?

Tags: python, list, append, iteration

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]

for i in start_list:
    start_list.append(i**2)
```

I was under the assumption that value of each list item is assigned to i while the iteration happens.

But given that the code above never completes - it looks like the list is being infinitely appended.

Why does this happen?

How could I properly write this so that It squares each element using the append function.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop only stops when it reaches the last element of the list object; by adding a *new* element in the loop body, there will *always* be more elements in the list.

Use a copy of the list when iterating, use indices, or use `list.extend()` with a list comprehension:

```
for i in start_list[:]:  # a copy won't grow anymore.
    start_list.append(i ** 2)
```

or

```
for idx in range(len(start_list)):  # the range is created just once
    start_list.append(start_list[idx] ** 2)
```

or

```
start_list.extend([i ** 2 for i in start_list]) # Append items from a new list
start_list += [i ** 2 for i in start_list]  # ditto, different spelling
```

If you actually meant to *replace* the values with their squared equivalents, just generate a new list from the old:

```
start_list = [i ** 2 for i in start_list]
```

Comment: I wonder, is `itertools.islice(start_list, len(start_list))` a bit too fancy-pants? In this context it's like `start_list[:]` except that it verbosely avoids making a copy.

Comment: @SteveJessop: perhaps; it's appropriate for a long list perhaps, but you may as well just use the index as that would be simpler and perhaps more readable.

Comment: I'd judge whether to use the index or not based on how many times `i` (or `start_list[idx]`) is mentioned in the loop body. One is marginal, any more than that and I'd want to avoid it even if eventually I decide to live with it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: sure, but that's easily remedied with `value = listobj[idx]`. There's a tradeoff here somewhere.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could make a copy of the list:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]

for i in list(start_list):
    start_list.append(i**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are facing the problem, because in each iteration, you are appending a new element, so it will never be finished.

To me, you want to replace each item with it's squared value. If you want that, you can do it like below:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
for index, i in enumerate(start_list):
    start_list[index] = i*i
print start_list
```

Output:

```
[25, 9, 1, 4, 16]
```

Using list comprehension, the solution will be like:

```
[i*i for i in start_list]
```

Output:

```
[25, 9, 1, 4, 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always a bad idea to modify a list while you iterate it, because any modifications are added to the iterator.

The best way to do this would be with a list comprehension:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
start_list += [i**2 for i in start_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending while iterating through the list, so it will never end as it grows infinitely. I would just use `+` to concatenate, and you can figure out the squares using a list comprehension.

```
>>> start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
>>> start_list += [i**2 for i in start_list]
>>> start_list
[5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25, 9, 1, 4, 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted an answer using append, here you go -

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]

for i in range(len(start_list)):
    start_list.append(start_list[i]**2)
```